# spring batch provide status of job execution and step information

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I have an application where clients send HTTP requests which get translated into Spring batch job params and trigger a job. I generate a `correlationId` for the response along with the result of the Job Execution.

At this point I have no way to get the `Job_Execution_Id` of the job that run.

The way to grab it is If I query `BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION_PARAM` table which has the `correlationId` as key/value, so I query with condition:

`where KEY_NAME='correlationId' AND STRING_VAL='12345'`

This gives me the `JOB_EXECUTION_ID`.

From here I want to provide my clients with the full detail of the job that run/or is running in progress including the details of the current step and its status. So json payload should look like something like this:

```
{
  "correlationId": "2ae16a63-7e91-4e37-942a-cf7f66117014",
  "jobDetails": {
    "id": 1,
    "jobId": 1,
    "jobName": "BLA BLA",
    "startTime": "2018-12-23T18:19:13.185",
    "endTime": "2018-12-23T18:19:13.223",
    "exitCode": "COMPLETED",
    "exitDescription": "",
    "status": "COMPLETED",
    "exceptions": [],
    "currentStep": "copyingAFile",
    "currentStepStatus": "RUNNING"
  },
  "_links": {
    "self": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/status/2ae16a63-7e91-4e37-942a-cf7f66117014"
    }
  }
}
```

I am aware there are some `dao` classes within spring batch for `jobexection` and `stepexecution`. What I'd like to know is if there a way I can grab the details of the job execution and the current step execution in one hit with a custom query or a dao method that already exists within the spring batch framework and plug into my response? All this from a simple correlationId that my client calls with in an endpoint  `GET /status/{correlationId}`

This [link](https://github.com/chrisgleissner/spring-batch-rest) has given me some knowledge but is querying with job execution id which my client will not have and also there is nothing about `currentStep` and it's status

I am not driving all this by job execution id because my jobs can be fired asynchronously for which I need to respond immediately with correlationId.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you don't need that `correlationId`. If you set an asynchronous task executor on the job launcher, the job launcher will return **immediately** a jobExecution with an id that you can return to the client, see [Running Jobs from within a Web Container](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.2.x/reference/html/job.html#runningJobsFromWebContainer).

Now with a job execution Id you get from `GET /status/{jobExecutionId}`, you can use a `JobExplorer#getJobExecution` to get the `JobExecution` and its step executions (using `JobExecution#getStepExecutions()`, and find out which step is currently running with `stepExecution.getStatus().isRunning()`. With that, you should be able to return your response.

Comment: yep aware that execution id is returned immediate when launcher is async, but to satisfy other requirements I use correlationId. question is more about a way of returning result job including job status, and current steps etc. Anyway to do return collectively job and step info or I need to write my own custom queries?

Comment: What I mention in my answer is actually a single hit to the db: `JobExplorer#getJobExecution`. From there you get the job execution and its step executions. With that, you can create your response (look for the job execution status, look for which step is currently running, etc).